# Efficient ORDER BY with dependent subquery on large tables

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, query-optimization

Using MySQL 5.7 (limited by Google Cloud SQL).

I have a large table (100,000s of rows), let's call it `cars`.

Then a relatively smaller table (10,000s of rows), let's call it `dealerships`.

Several times per second, data in `dealerships` and `cars` update and I need to be informed in real time of the updated order.

I need a complex ordering across multiple columns, and already have a composite index on `cars`, for example:

```sql
(`topSpeed` ASC, `heatedSeats` DESC, `mileage` DESC, `doors` ASC, `winterTyresIncluded` DESC)
```

I can query efficiently on `cars` alone, great.

However, I need to `group` the `cars` by `dealerships`, selecting the most relevant `cars` for each `dealerships`. The selected `cars` are needed for ordering the final results. Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `dealerships`
         INNER JOIN `cars` ON 
             `cars`.`dealershipId` = `dealerships`.`id` 
                 AND `cars`.`id` = (
                     SELECT id
                      FROM `cars`
                      WHERE `cars`.`status` IN ('pending')
                        AND `cars`.`dealershipId` = `dealerships`.`id`
                      ORDER BY `topSpeed` ASC,
                               `heatedSeats` DESC,
                               `mileage` DESC, `doors` ASC,
                               `winterTyresIncluded` DESC
                      LIMIT 1
                     )
WHERE `dealerships`.`isActive` = TRUE
ORDER BY `dealerships`.`updated` DESC, `cars`.`type` DESC, `dealerships`.`status` ASC, `cars`.`created` ASC
LIMIT 30;
```

This query is horrendously slow with my live database.
The `EXPLAIN` below is from my local environment:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: dealerships
   partitions: NULL
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,IDX_8b0666635781c2534cfdd3746c
          key: IDX_8b0666635781c2534cfdd3746c
      key_len: 36
          ref: NULL
         rows: 632
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: cars
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 36
          ref: func
         rows: 1
     filtered: 5.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: cars
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 36
          ref: func
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: cars
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_cars_composite
          key: idx_cars_composite
      key_len: 74
          ref: database.dealerships.id,const
         rows: 1148
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using filesort
4 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.18 sec)
```

- Am I ever going to be able to optimise the outer query's `ORDER BY` given it references fields from a joined table?
- Why does the dependent subquery on `cars` use filesort (4. row in the EXPLAIN) above? When run independently it uses the index `idx_cars_composite` with no filesort.
- Will I have to change my business logic or database technology to achieve efficient results?

Comment: If we have to use a correlated subquery, given the predicates in the WHERE clause, I'd want to dealershipId as leading columns in a composite index and as the first column in the ORDER BY. If the condition on the status column is always an equal to a single value 'pending', I'd want that as the next column in the index and ORDER BY.  My preference would be to try to rewrite the query to avoid the correlated subquery, since that subquery is going to be executed for every row returned by the outer query (every row that doesn't get filtered out before)

Comment: ... addendum to my previous comment ... it looks like idx_cars_composite index already has dealershipid and status as leading columns.  i'd add dealershipid and status columns to the beginning of the ORDER BY in the subquery ...

Comment: If it was me, I'd start over. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Q:*** Am I ever going to be able to optimise the outer query's ORDER BY given it references fields from a joined table?

***A:*** No, not without refactoring the table and/or query design. But I really question whether the ORDER BY on the outer query is the biggest issue. I suspect that the "big rock" in terms of query performance is that correlated subquery.

(What is the performance with the ORDER BY removed from the outer query?)

In terms of optimizing the performance of the ORDER BY we need to look at the size, the number of bytes, in the sort key, and the overall size of the row. We might be able to avoid sorts spilling to disk if we increase sort_buffer_size system variable. Do we really need to return *all* of the columns from dealerships and cars? Can we replace the lazy `*` with a specific list of expressions we actually need returned, and shorten up the row?

---

***Q:*** Why does the dependent subquery on cars use filesort (4. row in the EXPLAIN) above? When run independently it uses the index idx_cars_composite with no filesort.

***A:*** Looks like the correlated subquery is using index idx_cars_composite , based on the output from EXPLAIN it looks the leading columns in the index are dealershipid and status. If I was trying to avoid a Using filesort, and get the ORDER BY satisfied by the index, I would include the leading columns of the index  in the ORDER BY, and define the composite index with all of the columns that appear in the ORDER BY clause, in the same order.

```
   ORDER BY dealershipid
          , status
          , topspeed
          , heatedseats   DESC
          , mileage       DESC
          , doors
          , wintertyresincluded  DESC
```

and index

```
 ON cars (dealershipid, status, topspeed, heatedseats, mileage, doors, wintertyresincluded, id)
```

(I'm not really sure how the optimizer deals with a mix of ASC and DESC in the ORDER BY clause, and whether its possible to avoid a Using filesort operation. I do know that with MySQL 5.7, the ASC and DESC keywords that appear in the CREATE INDEX statement have no effect, indexes are always arranged in ascending sequence; things might be different in newer releases.)

My preference would be to attempt a rewrite of the query to avoid the (potentially expensive) repeated executions of the correlated subquery.

---

***Q:*** Will I have to change my business logic or database technology to achieve efficient results?

***A:*** No answer for that question.

Are we *sure* the query satisfies the specification?

Assuming id is the primary key of cars, it looks like we are returning only one car per dealerships.

And it Looks like the outer query is getting *all* cars for all active dealerships, which is potentially a lot of rows. For each one of those rows, the subquery is being executed, which will be a lot of executions. (It's not clear if the optimizer plan sees the subquery as deterministic, and avoids repeated calls for the same dealershipid or not.)

I would suggest testing a re-write of the query. Possibly something like this might be faster:

```
SELECT d.*
     , c.*
  FROM ( SELECT e.dealershipid
              , SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                  GROUP_CONCAT( e.id 
                    ORDER BY e.status
                           , e.topspeed
                           , e.heatedseats  DESC
                           , e.mileage  DESC
                           , e.doors
                           , e.wintertyresincluded  DESC
                    ,','
                    ,1
                  )
                ) AS carid
           FROM cars e
          WHERE e.status = 'pending'
          GROUP
             BY e.status
              , e.dealershipid
       ) r
  JOIN cars c
    ON c.id = r.carid
  JOIN dealerships d
    ON d.id = r.dealershipid
   AND d.isactive = TRUE
 ORDER
    BY d.isactive DESC
     , d.updated  DESC
     , c.type     DESC
     , d.status   ASC
     , c.created  ASC
 LIMIT 30
```

(NOTE: MySQL 5.7 does not support window/analytic functions, so we emulate with a hack to get the id values in order with GROUP_CONCAT( ... ORDER BY ...) and using SUBSTRING_INDEX to pull out the first id value, ) This query is going to be expensive for large sets.

Also note that with MySQL 5.7  the ASC and DESC keywords in the index definition are ignored; indexes are stored in ascending order.

We are assuming that status = 'pending' represents a relatively small subset of cars; again, I would want an index with status and dealershipid as the leading columns (to match  the equality predicate, and the GROUP BY)

Comment: Ended up using a combination of your suggestions and additional business logic which calculates the "most relevant car for each dealership" at time of _car_ insert/update, due to the lack of window functions and expense of group concat, etc.